# If I use delete in Javascript, what is the difference in var x, and simple x declaration?

Tags: javascript

```
x = 42;         // creates the property x on the global object
var y = 43;     // creates the property y on the global object, and marks it as non-configurable


// x is a property of the global object and can be deleted
delete x;       // returns true

// y is not configurable, so it cannot be deleted                
delete y;       // returns false
```

I dont understand what's mean the non-configurable. Why I can't delete the y?

Comment: `alert([window.x, window.y]) == "42,"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add a property to an object, you can make it configurable or non-configurable. The long hand version of your example:

```
x = 42;
```

Is

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
  value: 42,
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true
});
```

Configurable properties can be deleted, which removes them from the object (this may then lead to the memory being recovered, but it is not direct).

You could also write:

```
window.x = 42;
```

Which makes it more obvious when we come to the next issue.

```
window.x = 42; // x is a property
var y = 43; // y is not a property
```

And this is the real reason you can't delete `y`. It isn't a property and it isn't attached to an object. The delete keyword is for deleting a property from an object.

In the case of `y` - it will naturally be available for garbage collection when it cannot be reached (or when the reference count is 0 in older browsers).

You can also prevent properties from being deleted:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
  value: 42,
  writable: true,
  configurable: false,
  enumerable: true
});
```

This will cause either the `false` return from the attempt to delete it, or an error if you are running in strict mode.

Comment: Thanx this is the most understandable description.

Answer (score 7):

```
x = 42
```

is the same as

```
window.x = 42
```

i.e. create a property on the `window` object. Whereas

```
var y = 43
```

means 'create a variable in local scope'.

```
delete x
```

means

```
delete window.x
```

which probably does what you expect, but you can't use `delete` on a local variable. From the docs

> The delete operator removes a **property from an object**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

(my emphasis)

Comment: on a **local** variable

Answer (score 0):

The delete operator removes a property from an object. As `x` is a global variable it is a property of the global object. On the other hand `y` is just a variable with a non-global scope and therefore can't be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Because `delete` operator doesn't affect local variables

See [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) reference for more details

Answer (score 0):

Here `y` **is not a property** on the global object, `y` **is a variable**. 
And `delete` doesn't affect variable names, only variable properties. 
So it can't delete y.